# Laravel/Vue: Wrapping layout in Vue entry point but can't use in 'content' section

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have Laravel app that I wrapped in a Vue entry point, `<div id="app-shop"></div>`. I have Vue components I can use in the layout blade with no problem.  In the layout blade, I have `@yield('content')` to display other content.  One such section is the shopping cart, such as `/cart` route which yields my `cart.blade` file.  When I try to use the same component in the `cart.blade` though, it doesn't show.

**Cart.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    <div>
        <checkout-component></checkout-component>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Attempting to use it like this does not work.  I see no errors in the console but the component doesn't render.

Comment: Everything else is correct? Routes, including js and so on? Did you write `@extends ('layout.app)` in the first line of your `cart.blade.php`? Did you run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: @Commander yep! it's extending the layout in the `cart.blade.php` file.  I also tried clearing the cache, route and view as one of my first ways of trying to debug but not so luck.

Comment: Did you try to run `npm run dev` (yea i know it's the same component like in the other blade) and do a `hard reset` in your browser (ctrl+f5 or open dev tools, click and hold for a few seconds on the refresh button and select hard reset [this is for Chrome, don't know if Firefox works the same way])?